# Convert data processing to Excel function

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm currently working with excel file using Pandas. I have problem when export data to excel but not include how data had been calculated. Example :

```
  | A  | B
1 |Jame| 10
2 |Ann | 4
```

when I'm processing with this data

```py
df = pd.read_csv("data.xlsx")
sum_amount = df['amount'].sum()
```

When I export data to excel, I expect `sum_amount` would been recorded:

```
  | A  | B
1 |Jame| 10
2 |Ann | 4
3 |    | 14
```

With `B3 := SUM(B1:B2)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`XlsxWriter.writer_formula`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html)
Here is the working code:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['Jame','Ann'], 'B': [10,4]})  #df to be exported

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("formula.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")  #writer object
workBook = writer.book  #workbook object

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet1', index=False, header=False)  #write df to writer object

workSheet = workBook.get_worksheet_by_name(name='sheet1')  #worksheet object
workSheet.write_formula('B3', '=SUM(B1:B2)')  #write formula to worksheet object

writer.save()   #finally save the writer object
```

Here is the output Excel file, you can conform that it indeed stores the formula rather than just the value:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you are reading an excel file so you can't use **pd.read_csv**

Coming to your problem statement.

```
enter code here
total = df['B'].sum()
df = df.append({'B':total}, ignore_index=True)
```

This will give your desired result